# Find $A$ when $A^2$ is a $2\times 2$ zero-matrix and $A$ is symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra

> $A^2 = 
>        \begin{pmatrix}
>         0 & 0 \\
>         0 & 0 
>         \end{pmatrix}$ and $A$ is symmetric. Find the matrix $A$.

Well, I know that $A = A^T$ and $A^2 = 
       \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 
        \end{pmatrix}
$. I'm not sure how to continue from here. Any suggestions?

Btw, I thought of something: $A^2 = AA = A A^T = I$ but it is wrong.

Comment: Do you know that every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable? As in, is this a fact that you are aware of from class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left(\matrix{a & b\\ b & d}\right)^2=\left(\matrix{a^2+b^2 &  b(a+d)\\b(a+d) & b^2+d^2}\right)=\left(\matrix{0 & 0\\ 0 & 0}\right)\to b=0$ and $a^2=d^2=0$ or $a=-d$ and $b^2=-a^2$, ie, A is zero

Answer (score 4):

Here's a neat approach: for any matrix $A$ with entries $a_{ij}$, 
$$
\text{trace}(A^TA) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^2
$$
In our case, we know that $A^TA = 0$.

Comment: How would it prove that $A = 0$?

Comment: $a_{11}^2 + a_{12}^2 + a_{21}^2 + a_{22}^2$ is only zero if every $a_{ij}$ is zero, which is to say that $A = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2=0$. Take any $n\times 1$ column vector $x$; then
$$
0=x^TA^2x=x^TA^TAx=(Ax)^T(Ax)
$$
Therefore $Ax=0$. Hence $A=0$.

We use two facts:

1. If $y$ is an $n\times1$ column vector and $y^Ty=0$, then $y=0$.
2. If $Ax=0$ for all $n\times1$ column vectors, then $A=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix, first impose the condition of symmetricity and then square it and equate it to a zero matrix, you will get your answer. $A$ will be zero only.

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset math on this site with latex/mathjax. It is really easy to learn!

Comment: @Winther, thanks for the link.